# Python Компактность кода

Tags: python

Начал изучать язык. В книжке имеется такая задача: Написать программу которая меняет каждую цифру на "дополнение до 9"
Пример: Цифра 0 меняется на 9, Цифра 1 меняется на 8, цифра 2 меняется на 7.... Цифра 8 меняется на 1, Цифра 9 на 0.
Я написал код, но мне он кажется слишком громоздким.

```
x=int(input("Введите целое число: "))
y=0
if x==0:
    y=x+9
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==1:
    y=x+7
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==2:
    y=x+5
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==3:
    y=x+3
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==4:
    y=x+1
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==5:
    y=x-1
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==6:
    y=x-3
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==7:
    y=x-5
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==8:
    y=x-7
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
if x==9:
    y=x-0
    print("До числа 9 нехватает еще", (y))
```

Подскажите пожалуйста вариант как можно сделать его компактнее.
Я конечно попытаюсь сделать это сам например через while или elif.
Но хотелось бы увидеть пример от более продвинутых пользователей тоже
Спасибо!=*

Comment: Эм, вроде же просто в одну строку `y = 9 - x` не?

Comment: Собственно, можно всю программу целиком в одну строку записать `print('До числа 9 не хватает ещё', 9 - int(input('Введите целое число: ')))`

Comment: Вы забыли добавить "Пока правда". и условие выхода.

Comment: Использование множества if ещё можно объяснить, но зачем же тут куча вычислений типа y=x-1, если х заранее известен и можно было сразу вписать в строку нужное число.

Answer (score 5):

```
number = int(input("Введите целое число:"))  
print(f'Осталось {9 - number} до 9!')
```

Можно добавить исключение для чисел больше девяти и так далее. Просто пример того, как легко избавиться от условий и сократить код в несколько раз.

Answer (score 2):

Коллеги выше уже подсказали другое решение, но думаю рационально будет его записать сюда и добавить дополнительные объяснения.

```py
print(f'Осталось {9 - int(input("Введите целое число:")) } до 9!')
```

Теперь будем двигаться "от сложному к простому". Для начало разберёмся, как работают f-строки (для справки: данный синтаксис появился в версии Python 3.6). Они позволяют вставить код прямо в строку, что на самом деле очень удобно. Кстати, также он ускоряет код! Проверьте на досуге, если интересно.

Как это работает? Вы просто пишете строку в формате `f'Какая-то функция с аргументами 3 и 5: {any_func(3, 5)}'`. Преобразование типов при этом происходит автоматически.

Далее мы просто вызываем в фигурных скобках функцию `input()`, результат который преобразуем в целочисленное значение, а потом находим разность 9 и полученного значения.

Надеюсь, смог максимально понятно всё объяснить. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Целое число может состоять из нескольких цифр.

```py
x = input("Введите целое число: ")
# меняем каждую цифру на "дополнение до 9"
result = 10 ** len(x) - 1 - int(x)
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
Введите целое число: 3423455
6576544
```

Первый вариант работает некорректно с отрицательными числами. Второй вариант уже работает корректно. Также, можно подать любую строку на вход, будут заменяться только цифры:

```py
x = input("Введите целое число: ")
res = "".join(map(lambda i: str(9 - int(i)) if i.isdigit() else i, x))
print(res)
```

Вывод:

```
Введите целое число: -34234234
-65765765
```